# Return Complex JSON(object contains set) Using WCF LINQ-TO-SQL AND REST IN C# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, rest, linq-to-sql

In my web application i have an login page when user logged in i need to return to the web application the object Account Which Contains EntitiySet of Player :

```
public Account Login(string email,string password)
{
    var query = (from p in db.Accounts
                  where (p.EMAIL.Equals(email) && p.PASSWORD.Equals(password))
                  select new { EMAIL=p.EMAIL,PASSWORD=p.PASSWORD,NAME=p.NAME,Players=p.Players }).FirstOrDefault();
   return new Account { EMAIL = query.EMAIL, PASSWORD = query.PASSWORD, NAME = query.NAME,Players=query.Players};
}
```

Players is type of EntitySet

My Interface :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Login/{email}/{password}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Account Login(string email,string password);
```

If Account has no players , the get operation works and i can see the json returned .

```
{"EMAIL":"#####@gmail.com ","NAME":"Test","PASSWORD":"#####","Players":[]}
```

If Account has players , the browser just hangs out and nothing works .

I understand that its has something to do with the fact that players is an EntitySet , But how to accomplish that ?

Comment: Try calling ToList() on p.Players. You may also need to make a select.

Comment: Hi nice try , but i cannot create Account with List because List != EntitiySet  , REST should know how to do that behind the scene .

Comment: Ok...try selecting specific fields from p.Players, like p.Players.Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Whatever, p.Etc }); I'm betting the serializer is having difficulty with a circular property or something. I've run into a similar issue with entity framework 4.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately i should return Account And any change wont let me do the casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution i have found is to query account and his players EntitiySet separately i think the main problem is that players is type of EntitiySet inside the service due to LINQ-TI-SQL and REST don't know how to deal with that .

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Login/{email}/{password}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Account Login(string email,string password);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetPlayers/{email}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Player[] GetPlayers(string email);


public Account Login(string email, string password)
{
    var query = (from p in db.Accounts
                 where (p.EMAIL.Equals(email) && p.PASSWORD.Equals(password))
                 select new { EMAIL = p.EMAIL, PASSWORD = p.PASSWORD, NAME = p.NAME, Players = p.Players }).FirstOrDefault();
   return new  Account { EMAIL = query.EMAIL, PASSWORD = query.PASSWORD, NAME = query.NAME};         
}

public Player[] GetPlayers(string email)
{
    var query = (from p in db.Accounts
                 where (p.EMAIL.Equals(email))
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

    Player[] players = new Player[query.Players.Count];

    for(int i=0; i< players.Length; i++)
    {
        players[i] = new Player {FirstName = query.Players[i].FirstName,LastName=query.Players[i].LastName };
    }

    return players;
}
```

On GetPlayers i have tryd query.Players.toArray() not works also .